# Shared element return / reenter transition broken after configuration change

Tags: android, material-design, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I have activity A and B, with a shared element transition, which works just fine, until:

1. transition from A -> B in portrait orientation
2. in B, change orientation to landscape
3. hit back
4. the shared element doesn't know where to return, it just floats there stupidly in its place until the reenter transition finishes, then disappears

This looks awkward. I understand this is because originally the shared element was connected to the portrait landscape of A, and not to the landscape one. Can anything be done to alleviate the pain?

I checked the Google Play store app with the exact same scenario as described above, selecting an app from a list, then going back to the list after an orientation change. It seems to just pop back to the list without any animation, but that is already a lot better, as there's at least no broken transition and floating elements. What is the way to achieve this behavior?

**UPDATE**: Just to make it clear, the following scenario works *perfectly fine*:

1. transition from A -> B in portrait orientation
2. in B, change orientation to landscape
3. change orientation again, back to portrait
4. hit back
5. the shared element does its job perfectly and returns to A

So this is not the case where the view doesn't survive configuration changes.

Comment: Do you have an `android:id` on every element included in your shared element transition? Can you show your code?

Comment: Yes, I do have, and everything works fine if I switch back to portrait mode in activity B (so, double orientation change, first to portrait, then back to the original) before returning to A. Please advise, do I understand right the cause of the problem (stated in my original question)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question, at least the part regarding how to get back to the previous activity without a transition after an orientation change.

1. In the Activity `onCreate()`, create or restore a retained Fragment holding the original screen orientation
2. Override `onBackPressed()` and check if the current screen orientation is the same as the original. If not, just finish the Activity (no transition).

   ```
   private State state;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       initState();
   }

   private void initState() {
       String tag = "state";
       FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

       // find or create fragment
       this.state = (State) fm.findFragmentByTag(tag);
       if (this.state == null) {
           this.state = new State();
           fm.beginTransaction().add(this.state, tag).commit();

           // store original screen orientation
           this.state.originalOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
       // shared element would be broken
       if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != state.originalOrientation) {
           // no transition
           finish();

       } else {
           // default behavior
           super.onBackPressed();
       }
   }

   public static class State extends Fragment {
       private int originalOrientation;

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setRetainInstance(true);
       }
   }
   ```

It would obviously be better to fix the original problem, but no transition is still better than a broken one.